# Problem with nested timeouts in ruby over system calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, timeout

I ran into this weird issue while working with ruby(on rails) time outs. This time out

```
timeout(10) do
 //some code involving http calls that takes more than 10 seconds
end
```

is not working. But this timeout

```
timeout(20) do
 timeout(10) do
   //some code involving http calls that takes more than 10 seconds
 end
end
```

times out after 20 seconds. I read that timeout in ruby wont work properly if it involves system calls. If that be the case then any number of nested timeout should also not work. Why would this work on the second timeout?

The link I referred: http://ph7spot.com/musings/system-timer

Comment: which version of ruby are you running? and on which platform?

Comment: We are working on ruby 1.8.7 patch version 72 and platform is Debian linux(2.6.26)

Comment: FWIW, jruby implements real threads, so stuff like this works nicer.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck using a combination of `timeout` and [terminator](https://github.com/jeremyd/terminator) to do this sort of thing.

One of the known deficiencies of the `timeout` method is it's not always strictly enforced and many things can block it.